# JavaScript. I need to convert the strings to the same case before comparison using toLowerCase

Tags: javascript, compare, lowercase

I need to convert the strings to the same case before comparison using toLowerCase.

```
const firstValue = process.argv[2];
const secondValue = process.argv[3];
// Your comparison code (if statements) go here
let output = '';

if (firstValue<secondValue) {
output += '-1';
}

if (firstValue==secondValue) {
output += '0';
}

if (firstValue>secondValue) {
output += '1';
}

console.log(output);
```

In case firstValue=cats and secondValue=CATS result(output) should be 0 but its not, VisualStudio only allows use lowercase only in the end like `console.log(output.toLowerCase());` but it's after compare and i have no idea how to do it first.

ps Sorry, first time asking

Comment: What is the actual problem? What do you mean with "_VisualStudio only allows use lowercase only in the end_"? Visual Studio "allows" any valid code, you can do `const firstValue = process.argv[2].toLowerCase();`.

Comment: it works, thank you so much!!! i'm newbie sorry